# Can I check whether a number exist in a file?

Tags: bash, shell

I have this until now:

```
read -p "Enter your codenumber : " codenumber
echo "your codenumber is: $codenumber"
if grep -q 'codenumber' "$sin"
then
    echo "y"
else
    echo "n"
fi
```

What if I want to be able to check whether the codenumber exists in the file sin (as a first word $1)?

Comment: I think what you want is `grep -q "$codenumber" "$sin"` (with double quotes and `$` sign instead of `'codenumber'`)

Comment: nop! i did it that way too

Comment: please edit your Q to include a small sample data file, and your required output from that file. `grep -q "$codenumber"` should work. Did you `echo "codenumber=$codenumber"` to be sure? Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

I think you just made a typo:

```
grep -q "$codenumber" "$sin"
```

but note that this won't cover the case where a codenumber is part of another. If each codenumber is on a separate line; consider using:

```
grep -q "^$codenumber$" "$sin"
```

where

- ^ = start of line
- $ = end of line

**EDIT**: answer to the additional question: suppose the file contains lines like this:

```
218394 ted y ted
131241 john n ted
```

Here is how to get the 3rd column from the line that matches your $codenumber:

```
awk "/^$codenumber /{ print \$3 }" "$sin"
```

Comment: grep: : No such file or directory !! so no :P

Comment: @marv: does `$sin` contain a valid path? :)

Comment: that depends; where do you set the value of `sin`. There should be in your script something like sin=/path/to/file

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini what exactly do you mean ? :D

Comment: is there a way using awk/sed?

Comment: grep is a good option and it should work, but you're not giving him the correct path to your `sin` file... try adding a line this in your script: `sin="/path/to/sin.file"`

Comment: re-reading your question, I think you want `sin="$1"`, but I'm not 100% sure

Comment: ok thanks! what if i want exept the codenumber to check another part of a line! like i have this lines on the file 
{218394 ted y ted}
{131241 john n ted}
and i want to check if its y continue else dont (sorry to bother you) :D

Comment: that's another question. You should look around a little; this kind of questions have been asked over and over!

Comment: try something like this: `awk "/^$codenumber /{ print $3 }" $sin"

Comment: if your question is solved, consider accepting the answer so other people know that it is solved